# Asp.Net Core 3.0 Angular SPA template with Identity using Identity server home page User.Identity is null

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, identityserver4, razor-pages

I am using Asp.Net Core 3.0 Angular SPA template using authentication which uses Identity server. However I am using [SPA as an external application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization?view=aspnetcore-3.0#application-profiles).

All the identity server page are under Identity Area (Area/Identity). Therefore all the identity server pages follow these routes by convention.

`https://localhost:port/Identity/Account/*`

Login directly on Identity Server using route `Identity/Account/Login` works fine. And all the user admin routes detect the user is logged in. The template to display if user is logged in or not is in `Pages/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml`. I have created an Index.cshtml page as shown in following project layout. When navigate to Index page i.e at the root of the website, the User.Identity is not populated and header does not display if user is logged in hence displays Login and Register links. But in same session navigating to user admin pages user is still logged in.

So the issues is why User.Identity isn't populated for root URL?

This is my project structure.

[image]

Comment: You had to post controller authentication attributes, and appsettings to see what's missing, besides the server output of the requests to those views. Lots of info missing to answer anything here...